Zsh Function to Open Google Chrome with Search Query Opens Incorrect URL
I'm attempting to create a Zsh function on macOS that opens Google Chrome in a new tab. The function should:

Open a new blank tab when called without arguments.
Perform a Google
search when provided with a search query as an argument. Here's the
function I've added to my ~/.zshrc file:

 function openChrome() {
      if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        # No arguments provided; open a new tab
        open -na "Google Chrome" --args --new-tab
      else
        # Argument provided; perform a Google search
        local search_query="$*"
        local encoded_query=$(echo "$search_query" | sed 's/ /+/g')
        local google_search_url="https://www.google.com/search?q=$encoded_query"
        open -na "Google Chrome" --args "$google_search_url"
      fi
    }

Expected Behavior:

Running openChrome should open a new blank tab in Google Chrome.
Running openChrome "todays weather" should open a new tab in Google Chrome with a Google search for "todays weather".

Actual Behavior:

Running openChrome without arguments works as expected, opening a new blank tab.
Running openChrome "todays weather" opens a new tab with the URL http://todays%20weather/, which is not the intended Google search.

I've tried to url encode the argument in multiple ways but couldn't yield anything. Any help would be highly appreciated. TIA!

The function appears to work on my system. Are you "sourcing" the ~/.zshrc file after each edit? You may be testing with an old version of the code - functions openChrome will show what zsh has loaded, and debug printouts are always helpful.

Another possibility is that the alias you mentioned in a previous question is still active; type openChrome will help diagnose that. BTW, you may not need to encode the url - it looks like the app knows how to do it.

The issue for me was that I was NOT sourcing the .zshrc file. Doing it again and restarting the terminal seemed to work for me (in macOS Sequoia 15.1).
Thanks for all the help, I will mark the question as resolved.
